# Menu option is not working in tablet,but working in device

Tags: android, menu

In my app i am using the following code to display the menu.But it is working in device,not working in tablet.In my app i dont want to display title bar,for that i am using the following code in manifest file.
"....android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"...".By using this menu is working in device and not working in tablet.But when i removing "no titilebar " line in manifest it is working in tablet.but title bar is visible.Is there any possible menu is working without title bar.please help me.Thanks in advance

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ZOOM_OUT, Menu.NONE, "Zoom Out").setIcon(getZoomOutImageResource());
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ZOOM_IN, Menu.NONE, "Zoom In").setIcon(getZoomInImageResource());

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_MAIL, Menu.NONE, "Mail").setIcon(getMailImageResource());
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_PRINT, Menu.NONE, "Print").setIcon(getPrintImageResource());

    if (HardReference.sKeepCaches)
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CLEANUP, Menu.NONE, "Clear Caches");

    return true;
}

/**
 * Called when a menu item is selected.
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_NEXT_PAGE: {
        nextPage();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_PREV_PAGE: {
        prevPage();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_GOTO_PAGE: {
        gotoPage();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_ZOOM_IN: {
        zoomIn();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_ZOOM_OUT: {
        zoomOut();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_BACK: {
        finish();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_CLEANUP: {
        HardReference.cleanup();
        break;
    }
    case MENU_MAIL: {
        Uri mUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("file");
        try {
            sendemail(mUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    case MENU_PRINT: {
        myUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("file");
        printUSingPrinterShare();
        break;
    }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can set whatever theme you want, but with this code in the `onCreate()` : `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`. This should work on all the devices.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response

Comment: Let me know if it worked in your case, so I can paste it like an Answer. Thanks

Comment: sorry it is not working.